# How to set env variable or use instant client library in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-oracledb

Whwn using NodeJS function which connect to Oracle RDS, I'm getting the error:

> DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I'm following this deployment package structure:

```
instant_client_12.1
node_modules
index.js
```

Comment: There are similar questions (and answers) on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `libaio.so.1` in the /lib directory of the package your deploy to your Lambda?

As for the Env variables for Lambda, you can set these in the Console:
[image: LambdaEnv]

...or [using CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-environment.html)

Comment: I moved all instant client libraries with libaio.so into lib folder.1 and set symbolic link `ln -s libclntsh.so.12.1 libclntsh.so` and finally set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:/usr/lib64:$LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR:$LAMBDA_RUNTIME_DIR/lib:$LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT:$LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT/lib:/opt/lib` and still am getting same error